# Suggestions on how to make the following method generic

Tags: c#, .net, generics

I have multiple methods that do the following for a various different objects and I was wondering if there was a way to make this generic enough so that I don't need to write repetitive code.

```
    public UpsertEntities(IList<MyEntity> entities) {
        int totalImported = 0;
        int totalRecords = entities.Count();


        var options = new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 8 };



        var exceptions = new ConcurrentQueue<Exception>();
        var errors = new ConcurrentBag<string>();

        var batches = entities.ChunkBy(100);


        foreach (var batch in batches)
        {


            var loopResult = Parallel.ForEach(batch, options, e =>
            {
                try
                {
                    using (var context = GetContext())
                    {
                        context.SpecifiedEntityUpsert(e.Prop1, e.Prop2, e.Prop3, e.Prop4);
                    }
                    Interlocked.Increment(ref totalImported);
                }
                catch (Exception exception)
                {
                    exceptions.Enqueue(exception);

                    errors.Add("Error Import " + e.Id + " " + exception.Message);
                }

                if (totalImported % 1000 == 0)
                    LoggingEngine.Instance.Info(Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId + " - " + " Imported " + totalImported + " of " + totalRecords + " records ");
            });
        }

        foreach (var err in errors)
            LoggingEngine.Instance.Error(err);
     }
```

Thanks for any suggestions.

The part that are unique to each method is the method name, the parameter passed in and the following block of code:

```
                using (var context = GetContext())
                {
                    context.SpecifiedEntityUpsert(e.Prop1, e.Prop2, e.Prop3, e.Prop4);
                }
```

Comment: what is `SpecifiedEntityUpsert(e.Prop1, e.Prop2, e.Prop3, e.Prop4)`, is that always the same? Do all your types have `Prop1` to `Prop4` ?

Comment: Pass an `Action<Context, MyEntity>` that does the entity-specific upsert. In general, identify the specific bits and genericize them with a delegate or a virtual method.

Comment: No it's a entityframework stored procedure that's different for each entity

Comment: You have only shown one example of this duplicated code. Which parts are highly duplicated, and which parts are unique to each method?

Comment: Research the Repository pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only part in the code shown that is specific to the type is the call to `SpecifiedEntityUpsert`. You could abstract this out of the method and delegate it to an Action parameter instead.

**Call generic method**

```
var myList = new List<MyEntity>();
UpsertEntities(myList, (context, e) => context.SpecifiedEntityUpsert(e.Prop1, e.Prop2, e.Prop3, e.Prop4));
```

**Generic Method**

```
// I made a guess that context is of type DbContext
public UpsertEntities<T>(IList<T> entities, Action<DbContext, T> upsert) where T : class {
    int totalImported = 0;
    int totalRecords = entities.Count();

    var options = new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 8 };

    var exceptions = new ConcurrentQueue<Exception>();
    var errors = new ConcurrentBag<string>();
    var batches = entities.ChunkBy(100);

    foreach (var batch in batches)
    {
        var loopResult = Parallel.ForEach(batch, options, e =>
        {
            try
            {
                using (var context = GetContext())
                {
                    // call to action parameter
                    upsert(context, e);
                }
                Interlocked.Increment(ref totalImported);
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                exceptions.Enqueue(exception);
                errors.Add("Error Import " + e.Id + " " + exception.Message);
            }

            if (totalImported % 1000 == 0)
                LoggingEngine.Instance.Info(Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId + " - " + " Imported " + totalImported + " of " + totalRecords + " records ");
        });
    }

    foreach (var err in errors)
        LoggingEngine.Instance.Error(err);
 }
```

Comment: This is exactly what I couldn't figure out. Thanks so much!